# How do I summarise only part of a table?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two related use-cases in which I need to summarise just parts of a table, specified in a way similar to `filter`.

In a nutshell, I want something like this:

```
iris %>%
    use_only(Species == 'setosa') %>%
    summarise_each(funs(sum), -Species) %>%
    mutate(Species = 'setosa_sum') %>%
    use_all()
```

To yield this:

```
Source: local data frame [101 x 5]

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1         250.3       171.4         73.1        12.3 setosa_sum
2           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
3           6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
4           6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
5           5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
…
```

So instead of grouping by the value of a column, I use a filtering criterion to operate on a view of the table, without *actually losing* the rest of the table (unlike filter).

**How do I smartly implement `use_only`/`use_all`?** Even better, is this functionality already contained in `dplyr` and how do I use it?

It’s of course quite easy to generate the result above, but I need to do something similar for many different cases, with complex and variable criteria for filtering.

Comment: Why not just rbind with the rest of the data set at the end? Is it too slow/inefficient?

Comment: @konvas It’s messy when doing it more than once. My current code needs to do this for eight different criteria. I’ve obviously wrapped the logic to filter/summarise/rbind into a function, but it’s quite inflexible in the arguments that it expects, and is thus anything but a great API. Oh, and the function is specific to my particular DF layout, and consists of 15 lines.

Comment: Does the order of the returned rows matter? If the manipulated group is somewhere in the middle of the table, does it need to go back in the middle of the table? What if it is interspersed throughout and then summarized into a single row?

Answer (score 15):

I implemented this with the approach of having `use_only` save the rest of the table into a global option `dplyr_use_only_rest`, and having `use_all` bind it back together.

```
use_only <- function(.data, ...) {
    if (!is.null(.data$.index)) {
        stop("data cannot already have .index column, would be overwritten")
    }
    filt <- .data %>%
        mutate(.index = row_number()) %>%
        filter(...)

    rest <- .data %>% slice(-filt$.index)
    options(dplyr_use_only_rest = rest)
    select(filt, -.index)
}

use_all <- function(.data, ...) {
    rest <- getOption("dplyr_use_only_rest")
    if (is.null(rest)) {
        stop("called use_all() without earlier use_only()")
    }
    options(dplyr_use_only_rest = NULL)
    bind_rows(.data, rest)
}
```

I recognize setting global options is less than ideal design for functional programming, but I don't think there's another way to ensure that the remainder of the data frame passes through any intermediate functions untouched. Adding an extra attribute to the object wouldn't survive functions such as `do` or `summarize`.

At this point,

```
iris %>%
    use_only(Species == 'setosa') %>%
    summarise_each(funs(sum), -Species) %>%
    mutate(Species = 'setosa_sum') %>%
    use_all()
```

returns, as desired:

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1         250.3       171.4         73.1        12.3 setosa_sum
2           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
3           6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
4           6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
5           5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
...
```

Any intermediate steps could be used in place of `summarize_each` and `mutate` (`do`, `filter`, etc) and they would happen only to the specified rows. You could even add or remove columns (the remainder would be filled in with `NA`s).

Comment: Thanks. This seems the way to go. Using a global variable is obviously (…) completely unacceptable though — but we don’t need it, we can do what `group_by` does, and store the relevant detail in attributes (and use proper S3 dispatching while we’re at it). Once I find a minute ([sigh](https://twitter.com/klmr/status/586179796574588928)) I’ll have a go at it. I think a generalised version of this (“table views”) should probably find its way into dplyr proper.

Comment: @KonradRudolph As I note in my answer, I don't think we actually *can* store the extra data in an attribute though, since the intermediate `summarise_each` function would nuke them. E.g. `attr(mtcars, "extra") <- "stuff"`, followed by `mtcars %>% group_by(am) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean)) %>% attr("extra")` yields NULL.

Comment: @KonradRudolph To work around this one would have to replace the `summarise_each` function, or have `use_only` return a new tbl class with a new `summarise_each` method defined that wraps dplyr's (as well as `do`, `summarise`, or anything else one wanted to happen in the intermediate steps that would not preserve attributes). Is there another workaround I'm missing?

Comment: Huh, I completely missed that part. Odd. At any rate, I’d go as far as calling that a bug (although Hadley might disagree …). Overriding `summarise_` etc. is of course possible but that approach doesn’t scale if several functions nuke the attributes, or worse, if such functions are added in the future.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yeah, I wouldn't have suggested global if there were any other way :) I don't think it's a bug. `summarise` (etc) builds its output out of many outputs; it can't take responsibility for combining or preserving attributes beyond those `tbl_df` is expected to have. (What if some outputs have some attributes and other have others? And should it really check if the new output is missing any attributes the original input has? That's a design pattern I haven't seen).

Comment: Well, except for the `_join` functions all dplyr functions operate on *one* table (even if they use other data), which is the first argument to the functions. I don’t think it’s at all far-fetched to preserve its attributes. And we have a superb use-case here. Agreed, not (m)any other functions do this either but then other functions also don’t operate on this principle of pipelines which makes this behaviour desirable in the first place.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I meant in terms of combining outputs from each summary operation. Though I suppose it could just look at attributes of the original, unsummarized data. Incidentally, the dplyr version of eddi's answer would be something close to `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% do(if (.$Species[1] == "setosa") summarise_each(., funs(sum), -Species) else select(., -Species))`

Comment: *I think a generalised version of this (“table views”) should probably find its way into dplyr proper.* Out of curiosity, has a function found its way in `{dplyr}`?

Answer (score 15):

I think your approach of searching for a function to satisfy that particular syntax is too restrictive. This is what I would do using `data.table` (I'm not sure if `dplyr` allows for variable rows like this yet, I know it's been an FR for a while):

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(iris)

dt[, if (Species == 'setosa') lapply(.SD, sum) else .SD, by = Species]
#        Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#  1:     setosa        250.3       171.4         73.1        12.3
#  2: versicolor          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4
#  3: versicolor          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5
#  4: versicolor          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5
#  5: versicolor          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3
# ---
```

You can also add `[Species == 'setosa', Species := 'setosa_sum']` at the end to modify the name in place. It should be straightforward to extend to multiple criteria/whatever function.

Comment: This is not a bad solution (and really shows how easy a solution *should* be) but I’m somewhat committed to dplyr now.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by being committed - (a) `dplyr` works with data.tables, and (b) `data.table` has `setDT` and `setDF` functions for going back and forth between `data.frame` and `data.table` in place.

Comment: By “committed” I mean committed to one API. I don’t want to mix several APIs which do essentially the same thing …

Comment: meh, by the extension of that argument you should stay in base. imo the way of R is to use any and all packages you can to achieve what you want in simplest and fastest form

Comment: The point is that I’m in a middle of a pipeline and I don’t want to break up the expression. Otherwise I could also just simply manually split up the table, perform the operation, and stitch it back together.

Comment: Sounds like you want to pipeline for the sake of pipelining - that's your choice obviously, but I don't think it's a wise approach. And this option is imo fundamentally different from manually splitting and stitching back together. Anyway, you have the options and can choose to do whatever you want, all I'm saying is that whatever commitment you think you have is entirely imaginary.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Nothing prevents you from using `data.table` in the middle of a pipeline: `iris %>% setDT %>% "["(., ,if (Species == 'setosa') lapply(.SD, sum) else .SD, by = Species)`; this can be combined with `dplyr` expressions as well.

Comment: @BrodieG “can be” is not the same as “should be”. That’s a horribly unreadable mess. In fact, I’m not a big fan of the data.table syntax to begin with, but combining it in this way with dplyr pipes … no. My foremost aim is to write understandable, maintainable code which is (as far as possible) obviously error-free. Using such convolutions is counter-productive. As I’ve alluded to before, there are tons of viable solutions via temporary variables. Making a *readable* solution is what I was after.

Comment: @KonradRudolph then hide the convolution in a function, as the other answers do here (and which you seem to be okay with).  I will point out, for the sake of the argument, that this **by far** the least convoluted of all the answers.

Comment: @BrodieG That’s missing the point. Of course this answer can be hidden in a function. But I’m interested in a *general* API, like the one David provided. I don’t care whether that is internally implemented via data.table or something else, but I have no idea how to adapt this answer to such an API — hence this comment discussion. As for whether this is the least convoluted answer, I’d have to agree, but I actually find this unsatisfactory insofar as it shows that the dplyr API is lacking expressiveness.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a new column to group by:

```
iris %>%
  mutate( group1 = ifelse(Species == "setosa", "", row_number()))  %>%
  group_by( group1, Species ) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum), -Species, -group1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group1)
```

#### Update - as more general solution

```
library(lazyeval)

use_only_ <- function(x, condition, ...) {
  condition <- as.lazy(condition, parent.frame())
  mutate_(x, .group = condition) %>% 
    group_by_(".group", ...)
}

use_only <- function(x, condition, ...) {
  use_only_(x, lazy(condition), ...)
}

use_all <- function(x) {
  ungroup(x) %>%
    select(- .group)
}
```

Use `use_only` with any condition in the context of data frame and calling environment. In this case:

```
iris %>%
  use_only( ifelse(Species == "setosa", "", row_number()), "Species") %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum), -Species, -.group) %>%
  use_all()
```

The `use_only_` can be used with formula or string. For example:

```
condition <- ~ifelse(Species == "setosa", "", row_number())
```

or

```
condition <- "ifelse(Species == 'setosa' , "", row_number())"
```

And call:

```
iris %>%
  use_only_(condition, "Species") %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum), -Species, -.group) %>%
  use_all()
```

When mutate-ing between the `use_only` and `use_all` calls you must take care to change only values inside marked group.

Comment: You probably want an `ungroup()` before the `select(-group1)`, since `select` can't remove grouping columns.

Comment: Note that this won't work for non-summary operations such as the `mutate` in the OP's example, or for summary operations that when performed on one row don't preserve the same row (though perhaps those can be worked around and aren't necessary for the OP's situation!)